# How can I change javascript quiz results to weight based scoring?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to build a multiple choice test using javascript, that displays one question at a time (fading to the next question). after all the questions have been answered, then depending on your answers it gives you your results. The results of the actual questions don't need to be displayed just a score and explanation of that score as the result will be a bunch of text.

For example:

- a score of 0-20 = result 1
- 21-50 = result 2
- 51-60 = result 3
- 61-80 = result 4
- 81 - 100 = result 5

Below is my code, how can I change it so that no answer is "correct" it simply gives a text result at the end of the quiz depending on the range of the score as stated above?

Javascript:

```
 (function() {
var questions = [{
question: "Question1",
choices: ["choice1", "choice2", "choice3"],
correctAnswer:0
}, {
question: "Question2",
choices: ["choice1", "choice2", "choice3"],
correctAnswer: 4
}, {
question: "Question3",
choices: ["choice1", "choice2", "choice3"],
correctAnswer: 0
}, {
question: "Question4",
choices: ["choice1", "choice2", "choice3"]
correctAnswer: 3
}, {
question: "Question5",
choices: ["choice1", "choice2", "choice3"],
correctAnswer: 4
}];

var questionCounter = 0; //Tracks question number
var selections = []; //Array containing user choices
var quiz = $('#quiz'); //Quiz div object

// Display initial question
displayNext();

// Click handler for the 'next' button
$('#next').on('click', function (e) {
e.preventDefault();

// Suspend click listener during fade animation
if(quiz.is(':animated')) {        
  return false;
}
choose();

// If no user selection, progress is stopped
if (isNaN(selections[questionCounter])) {
  alert('Please make a selection!');
} else {
  questionCounter++;
  displayNext();
}
});

// Click handler for the 'prev' button
$('#prev').on('click', function (e) {
e.preventDefault();

if(quiz.is(':animated')) {
  return false;
}
choose();
questionCounter--;
displayNext();
});

// Click handler for the 'Start Over' button
$('#start').on('click', function (e) {
e.preventDefault();

if(quiz.is(':animated')) {
  return false;
}
questionCounter = 0;
selections = [];
displayNext();
$('#start').hide();
});

 // Animates buttons on hover
 $('.button').on('mouseenter', function () {
 $(this).addClass('active');
 });
 $('.button').on('mouseleave', function () {
 $(this).removeClass('active');
 });

  // Creates and returns the div that contains the questions and 
  // the answer selections
  function createQuestionElement(index) {
  var qElement = $('<div>', {
  id: 'question'
  });

  var header = $('<h2>Question ' + (index + 1) + '</h2>');
  qElement.append(header);

  var question = $('<p>').append(questions[index].question);
  qElement.append(question);

  var radioButtons = createRadios(index);
  qElement.append(radioButtons);

  return qElement;
  }

  // Creates a list of the answer choices as radio inputs
  function createRadios(index) {
  var radioList = $('<ul>');
  var item;
  var input = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < questions[index].choices.length; i++) {
  item = $('<li>');
  input = '<input type="radio" name="answer" value=' + i + ' />';
  input += questions[index].choices[i];
  item.append(input);
  radioList.append(item);
   }
   return radioList;
   }

   // Reads the user selection and pushes the value to an array
   function choose() {
   selections[questionCounter] = +$('input[name="answer"]:checked').val();
   }

   // Displays next requested element
    function displayNext() {
    quiz.fadeOut(function() {
    $('#question').remove();

    if(questionCounter < questions.length){
    var nextQuestion = createQuestionElement(questionCounter);
    quiz.append(nextQuestion).fadeIn();
    if (!(isNaN(selections[questionCounter]))) {
     $('input[value='+selections[questionCounter]+']').prop('checked', true);
    }

    // Controls display of 'prev' button
    if(questionCounter === 1){
      $('#prev').show();
    } else if(questionCounter === 0){

      $('#prev').hide();
      $('#next').show();
    }
  }else {
    var scoreElem = displayScore();
    quiz.append(scoreElem).fadeIn();
    $('#next').hide();
    $('#prev').hide();
    $('#start').show();
  }
  });
  }

  // Computes score and returns a paragraph element to be displayed
  function displayScore() {
  var score = $('<p>',{id: 'question'});

  var numCorrect = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < selections.length; i++) {
  if (selections[i] === questions[i].correctAnswer) {
    numCorrect++;
  }
}

score.append('You got ' + numCorrect + ' questions out of ' +
             questions.length + ' right!!!');
return score;
}
})();
```

HTML:

```
<div class="col-md-6" style="padding:10px;">
<h4 class="text-center lead" style="color:#333;font-size:28px;"> Relationship Test </h4>
<div class="test">
<a id="update" href="index.html" class="pull-right"><i style="color:#333;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-repeat glyphicon-repeat-animate"></i></a> 

<p id="quiz" class="lead quiz-1" style="color:#333;padding:20px;"> </p> 
</div>
 <div style="margin-top:5px;">

<a type="" id="next" href="#tellme" class="button btn btn-block testbuttons"  onclick="" >Next </a>
<a type="" id="prev" href="#tellme" class="button btn btn-block testbuttons"  onclick="" >Previous </a>
<a type="" id="start" href="#tellme" class="button btn btn-block testbuttons"  onclick="" >Start Over </a>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by `so that no answer is "correct" `? If they don't have an answer how d oyou want to score?

Comment: There is no right answer. I'm trying to make it displays text explanation at the end not a score.

Comment: An explanation of what?

Comment: Your array of objects `quiz` is not valid. Just pointing that out unless typo. `choice4` should have a `"` in the beginning.

Comment: I just want to point out that "correctAnswer: 3" and "correctAnswer: 4" is invalid because there are only 3 elements (0, 1, 2) in the "choices" object, so trying to reference the correct answer to "correctAnswer" will not work.

Comment: @Achraf Almouloudi That is the question, how can you make is so there is no "correct answer" and the quiz just provides feed back depending on the answers. like a questionnaire.

Comment: To do that, you should give a "weight" of points to each possible answer in each question, then you simply sum up  the accumulated points and see which "result" range it reaches to output the appropriate text explanation of the score.

Comment: yes! that's it. but i don't know how to do that . . . :P still learning. here is an example http://www.mylifetime.com/fun-quizzes/style/what-s-your-dream-home-style

Comment: Check my answer, I've given an example of giving "weight" to each choice, and don't forget to mark as answer and/or upvote if you find it useful.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how your question's responses could have have "weight" in determining the final result on a range of 0-100 and what's in between:

```
var questions = [
    {
        question: "Question1",
        choices: [
                    "choice1",
                    "choice2",
                    "choice3"
                    ],
        weights: [10, 7, 3]
    },
    {
        question: "Question2",
        choices: [
                    "choice1",
                    "choice2",
                    "choice3"
                    ],
        weights: [3, 10, 7]
    },
    {
        question: "Question3",
        choices: [
                    "choice1":10,
                    "choice2":0,
                    "choice3":10
                    ],
        weights: [10, 0, 10]
    },
    {
        question: "Question4",
        choices: [
                    "choice1",
                    "choice2",
                    "choice3"
                    ],
        weights: [3, 10, 7]
    },
    {
        question: "Question5",
        choices: [
                    "choice1",
                    "choice2",
                    "choice3"
                    ],
        weights: [10, 3, 7]
    }
];
```

What I did is take the highest possible score, which is 100 and divide it by the number of question I'm giving, which is 5 in this case, then divide the 20 points per question unequally (and that's important) between the answers, giving more points to the "best" answer and less or 0 points to the "worst" answer.

Notice I always made sure all the points in any given question equal 20 so the that each question's choices will be "fair" in determining the score. I hope that solves the "no correct answer" part of your  question.

**UPDATE:** I have updated the code to make it easier to process the answers.

In the "new" version, you have a "weights" array for each question, the weight numbers should correspond to each "choice" respectively. In your application, each question should be processed as such:

Fetch the "question" value and display it in an HTML tag.
Get the choices from the "choices" array and display them inside an HTML select options tag, like this example:

```
<select id="response">
    <option value="10">Best answer</option>
    <option value="7">Moderate answer</option>
    <option value="3">Worst answer</option>
</select>
```

And the weight value should be in the `value="x"` of each option, just like the example above. You can use the `each()` function from jQuery (I assume you're using Bootstrap, so you already have it) to iterate through the questions.

Each questions "submit" button should call your `choose()` function, which should be updated to retrieve the `value="x"` value and add it to the `selections[]` array.

The, you should update the `displayScore()` function to just sum up the values from the `selections[]` array, in this way:

```
var total = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < selections.length; i++) {
    total += selections[i];
}
```

And compare the `total` variables to your result ranges (0-20, 21-40, 41-60, 61-80, 81-100) using `if else if` and for each `if` it should `return` the text "explanation" you want to give for the score, and probably the score itself.

Finally, you will just have to print the result of `displayScore()` using `document.write()`  inside the HTML tag where you want to show the results the the user.

Comment: thats perfect! :) So do I leave the rest of the js like it is?

Comment: Check my update, I have described the application flow you should implement for your quiz to work. Please don't forget to mark it as the answer if you think it deserves it.

Comment: I've been trying for the past few hours, I can't seem to get it.

Comment: Try to follow the method I've described and post new questions if you encounter "unsolvable" issues, after researching online of course. Remember, StackOverflow questions are meant to solve a specific code problem, not help the asker create the whole project.

Answer (score 1):

I forked your pen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XXKeaN
Think I've fixed it.

Please look at the answers, which hold the value to the choices.
The checkAnswer() function calculates this, specifically this line

```
score = score + quiz[currentQuestion].answer[i];
```

The output is at the end, just showing a singular score.

Comment: Really sorry, I posted the wrong js. I have added the correct js now. But yes the idea is to provide feedback to the user depending on the range.

Comment: nice) i had a look, what result is that displaying tho?

Comment: The values based on your selection, as defined in the arrays on top of the script